# Parse Command Outputting Horizontally

Tags: parsing, powershell, logging

I have a script that parses a log file for the last 15 lines but it outputs the data in a horizontal line which I think interferes when I try to get an average of the numbers in the file.

Here's an example of the log file I'm parsing:

```
3/22/2016 9:11:21 AM 44.0
3/22/2016 9:11:22 AM 44.1
3/22/2016 9:11:23 AM 44.2
3/22/2016 9:11:24 AM 44.3
```

And here's my PowerShell command that parses the last 15 lines of the active log file.

```
$regexNUM = '\d+\.\d+'

$NUMLog = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents' |
          Where-Object {$_.Name -match "LOGFILE"} |
          Sort LastWriteTime | Select -Last 1

$NUMBERS = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\$NumLog" -Tail 15 |
           Select-String -Pattern $regexNum -AllMatches |
           % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups }
```

When I do a `Write-Host $NUMBERS` it outputs the data like this:

```
39.5 39.6 39.7 39.8 39.9 40.0 40.1 40.2 40.3 40.4 40.5 40.6 40.7 40.8 40.9
```

And here's how I'm trying to get the average of these 15 numbers:

```
$Average = $NUMBERS | Measure-Object -Average | Select Average
```

When I do `Write-Host $Average` it says:

```
Measure-Object : Input object "39.5" is not numeric.
At C:\Users\Admin\Documents\SampleTest.ps1:26 char:30
+ $Average = $NUMBERS | Measure-Object -Average | Select Average
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (39.5:Match) [Measure-Object], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonNumericInputObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

I'm not sure why it would say the number 39.5 is not numeric but all I can assume is that it doesn't like it being horizontal with the spaces maybe. It throws one of those errors for each of the 15 numbers too.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem:

The problem in your code is that you are actually feeding objects of type `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` to the `Measure-Object` cmdlet, and not numbers.

The `Write-Host` command is automatically converting the `Match` object to text when it needs to output it to the console, and that makes you think it looks like numbers.

#### Solution:

To fix that, change the following line to get values inside the `Match` objects:

```
$NUMBERS = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\$NumLog" -Tail 15 |
           Select-String -Pattern $regexNum -AllMatches |
           % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

#### Advice:

To fix problems like this yourself, you can use the the `Get-Member` cmdlet to check what is the type returned.

In your case, you can send the output of the second `Get-Content` cmdlet to `Get-Member`, instead of saving it to a variable:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\$NumLog" -Tail 15 |
    Select-String -Pattern $regexNum -AllMatches |
    % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups } | Get-Member
```